# Casting std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> and std::shared_ptr<T> with same function but different overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, shared-ptr

In my current project we are building for Linux and Windows at the same time. 
Unfortunately because some platform issues our MSVC is very old. We are using MSVC 2010. And gcc we are using relatively new and smarter which has the version 4.8 .

The code below compile in gcc but MSCV nags about it :

```
template<class T, class U>
std::shared_ptr<T> Cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& spObject )   // rename from CastTerrainObject
{
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(spObject);
}

template<class T, class U>
std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> Cast( const std::tr1::shared_ptr<U>& spObject ) // rename from CastTerrainObject
{
    return std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(spObject);
}
```

MSVC began nagging after I add the second overload for std::tr1::shared_ptr.
The compile errors I am getting repeatedly :

```
error C2995: 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> Cast(const std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty2> &)' : function template has already been defined

And 

 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> (__cdecl *)(const std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty2> &)' to 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>'
```

Do you guys have a solution for my case?

Comment: `#ifdef` it out on platforms it does not work?

Comment: It might be that one of them is a `using shared_ptr =  the other one`. In that case it is the same type, and cannot be used for overloading.

Comment: @Yakk I wish I could test it easily but once I make a change auto build machine will be triggered and build the process will take like 1-2 hours. Unfortunately I need to be sure first than apply.

Comment: @BoPersson I think that is the problem too. But as I told in prev. comment unfortunately I need to be sure at least like %90 percent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `Cast` function template take a template template parameter:

```
template<typename T, template<class> class SP, class U>
SP<T> Cast2(SP<U> const& sp) {
    using std::dynamic_pointer_cast;
    using std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast;
    return dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(sp);
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sYU7WHYdjdK0MBMK)

---

Leaving the original answer for posterity. *It is ill-formed on VC++* (though it works as expected), because there is no valid specialization of the function.

Disable the second overload if `std::shared_ptr` and `std::tr1::shared_ptr` are the same thing (they are on VC++ 10, they are not for my gcc).

```
template<class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same< std::shared_ptr<T>, std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> >::value,
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>
>::type
Cast( const std::tr1::shared_ptr<U>& spObject ) // rename from CastTerrainObject
{
    return std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(spObject);
}
```

The following compiles on both VC++ 10 and the [latest gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k8vOwBSBRJviTBdD). Unfortunately, it's ill-formed on VC++10 (despite working as expected)

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#ifndef _WIN32
#include <tr1/type_traits>
#include <tr1/shared_ptr.h>
#endif

template<class T, class U> // rename from CastTerrainObject
std::shared_ptr<T> Cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& spObject )
{
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(spObject);
}

template<class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same< std::shared_ptr<T>, std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> >::value,
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>
>::type
Cast( const std::tr1::shared_ptr<U>& spObject ) // rename from CastTerrainObject
{
    return std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(spObject);
}

struct B{ virtual ~B(){} };
struct D:B{};

int main()
{
    Cast<B>(std::make_shared<D>());
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k8vOwBSBRJviTBdD)

You could also ifdef the second overload away, but I'm not sure which conditions should be checked.

Comment: That approach is much more better than the #ifdef approach from my point of view. Testing now

Comment: The only downside is you end up with an ill formed program that happens to compile.  This technique is not legal C++, but the standard states no diagnostic is required in this case (as determining that no specialization of a template function can be valid is Halt-hard).

Comment: @Yakk why is it ill-formed?

Comment: All templates must have a set of template arguments that permit it to be instantiated.  (There are additional restrictions, like one valid specialization for parameter packs must be non-empty).  I suspect this ito permit additional "early" checks by the compiler; regardless of the reason behind the rule, it means code containing such templates means the behaviour of every part of your entire program is not defined by the standard.  The most common "problem" is some compiler actually detects it and generates an error.

Comment: As I know enable_if is being used so often in boost libraries. So If it is ill-formed than ours project already is ill-formed and also many other projects. Am I missing a point maybe?

Comment: @kadir enable if *with the fact that some set of arguments passes the test* is valid C++.  This is not the case here.  On msvc, no `T` passes the test.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk, I managed to fool myself that it's well formed because there are valid instantiaions for gcc :) I'll try to find a way around it.

Comment: `template<class T, template<class...>class sp, class U> sp<T> Cast( sp<U, std::default_delete<U>> const& )`?  That removes code duplication as a bonus.

Comment: Guys sorry from my side maybe I should make another question and ask about it. I want to learn a lot reading over and over your comments but I still can't see the problem.

Comment: @Yakk the biggest problem is that VC++ is barely a c++ compiler - if that ;) And here the requirement is to use a fairly old verison of it

Comment: @kadir on msvc there is zero possible `T` that makes the template in this answer legal.  This is explicitly illegal under the standard, and compilers are explicitly permitted to generate no error message despite it being illegal (an ill-formed program).  There is nothing else to understand.  It may compile and work, but that does not mean it is valid C++.

Comment: @Yakk working with this VS2010 a chore. Would you mind checking [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wHnB7agqI4GW7QjT) over? It does compile successfully on both compilers. God, I'm so used to variadic templates and templated type aliases...

Comment: Kr, take the code in my comment, get rid of `...`, pass deleter explicitly, should work in both gcc and msvc and be legal C++.

Comment: Actually, [just get rid of `...`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12be4ffc0f3b304b)

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir please see the edit and/or Yakk's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a `Cast` that can take *either* `std::tr1::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` in one `template` function.  This follows DRY (don't repeat yourself) and avoids subtle pitfalls with alternative solutions:

```
template<class T, template<class>class Sp, class U>
Sp<T> Cast( const Sp<U>& spObject )
{
  typedef Sp<T> R;
  // manual implementation of the dynamic shared cast
  // as we don't know if we want to use tr1 or not:
  T* out = dynamic_cast<T*>(spObject.get());
  if (!out)
    return R();
  // alising ctor, shares refcount block with spObject 
  // but uses out pointer:
  return R( spObject, out ); 
}
```

This is legal C++ and should work for both a `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and a `std::shared_ptr`.

Any template function you write must have a set of template argument that, if you pass them in, the template is valid.  Failure to do this makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12be4ffc0f3b304b).

The fears I have is that MSVC2010 might not propery deduce template template arguments (I mean, that is C++03, but this is MSVC2010), or that `std::tr1::shared_ptr` might be missing the alising ctor.

If you need to restrict `Cast` to only work with `std::shared_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, you could add a SFINAE test that `Sp<U>` is one of those two.

```
std::is_same< std::shared_ptr<U>, Sp<U> >{}
|| std::is_same< std::tr1::shared_ptr<U>, Sp<U> >{}
```

but I doubt that is required.  The test becomes redundant on a system where they are the same type, but redunant tests are legal, redundant overloads are not.

Comment: After changing the type alias from using to a typedef it compiles on VC10.